# Creating an overlay to send a message

Tags: jquery, html, css, overlay, modal-dialog

I'm looking for similiar functionality like Facebook when someone clicks the send a message button a div pops up with a textarea that people can type in. I'm not sure how to go about creating the overlay though. I've looked at things like Facebox but want to create something on my own. Do anyone have any good examples or tutorials on how to create this overlay with a lot of elements on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the cleanest modals out there is the one provided in the [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). To implement it, you just need to be using **[jQuery](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js)** and **[modal.js](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap-modal.js)**. As per your additional request for alerts, you will also need to add **[alert.js](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap-alerts.js).** If you don't want to use [their CSS](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap.css), it's relatively easy to implement in your CSS as well:

HTML:

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="my-modal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
    <h3>Modal Heading</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn primary">Primary</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn secondary">Secondary</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="alert-message success hide fade in" data-alert="alert">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
    <p><strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully <a href="#">read this</a> alert message.</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#my-modal').modal(true);
$(".alert-message").alert();
$('#my-modal').bind('hidden', function () {
    $(".alert-message").removeClass("hide");
});
```

You might end up using something other than `bind()` to fire the `removeClass()` function.

CSS:

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.fade {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
  transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
  opacity: 0;
}
.fade.in {
  opacity: 1;
}
.close {
  float: right;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 13.5px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
  filter: alpha(opacity=25);
  -khtml-opacity: 0.25;
  -moz-opacity: 0.25;
  opacity: 0.25;
}
.close:hover {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  filter: alpha(opacity=40);
  -khtml-opacity: 0.4;
  -moz-opacity: 0.4;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
/* Modal */
.modal-backdrop {
  background-color: #000000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10000;
}
.modal-backdrop.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}
.modal-backdrop, .modal-backdrop.fade.in {
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
  -khtml-opacity: 0.8;
  -moz-opacity: 0.8;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 11000;
  width: 560px;
  margin: -250px 0 0 -280px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  *border: 1px solid #999;
  /* IE6-7 */

  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
.modal .close {
  margin-top: 7px;
}
.modal.fade {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
  transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
  top: -25%;
}
.modal.fade.in {
  top: 50%;
}
.modal-header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
.modal-body {
  padding: 15px;
}
.modal-body form {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.modal-footer {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  padding: 14px 15px 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
  zoom: 1;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.modal-footer:before, .modal-footer:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  zoom: 1;
}
.modal-footer:after {
  clear: both;
}
.modal-footer .btn {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.modal .popover, .modal .twipsy {
  z-index: 12000;
}
/* Alerts */
.alert-message.danger,
.alert-message.danger:hover,
.alert-message.error,
.alert-message.error:hover,
.alert-message.success,
.alert-message.success:hover,
.alert-message.info,
.alert-message.info:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.alert-message .close {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 18px;
}
.alert-message.danger,
.alert-message.error {
  background-color: #c43c35;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-image: -khtml-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ee5f5b), to(#c43c35));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ee5f5b, #c43c35);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ee5f5b, #c43c35);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ee5f5b), color-stop(100%, #c43c35));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ee5f5b, #c43c35);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ee5f5b, #c43c35);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ee5f5b, #c43c35);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ee5f5b', endColorstr='#c43c35', GradientType=0);
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-color: #c43c35 #c43c35 #882a25;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.alert-message.success {
  background-color: #57a957;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-image: -khtml-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#62c462), to(#57a957));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #57a957);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #57a957);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #62c462), color-stop(100%, #57a957));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #57a957);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #57a957);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #57a957);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#62c462', endColorstr='#57a957', GradientType=0);
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-color: #57a957 #57a957 #3d773d;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.alert-message.info {
  background-color: #339bb9;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-image: -khtml-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#5bc0de), to(#339bb9));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #339bb9);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #339bb9);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #5bc0de), color-stop(100%, #339bb9));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #339bb9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #339bb9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #339bb9);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#5bc0de', endColorstr='#339bb9', GradientType=0);
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-color: #339bb9 #339bb9 #22697d;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
:root .alert-message {
  border-radius: 0 \0;
}
.alert-message {
  position: relative;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  color: #404040;
  background-color: #eedc94;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-image: -khtml-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fceec1), to(#eedc94));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fceec1, #eedc94);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fceec1, #eedc94);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fceec1), color-stop(100%, #eedc94));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fceec1, #eedc94);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fceec1, #eedc94);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fceec1, #eedc94);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fceec1', endColorstr='#eedc94', GradientType=0);
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-color: #eedc94 #eedc94 #e4c652;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}
.alert-message .close {
  margin-top: 1px;
  *margin-top: 0;
}
.alert-message a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #404040;
}
.alert-message.danger p a,
.alert-message.error p a,
.alert-message.success p a,
.alert-message.info p a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.alert-message h5 {
  line-height: 18px;
}
.alert-message p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.alert-message div {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  line-height: 28px;
}
.alert-message .btn {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}
.alert-message.block-message {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #fdf5d9;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
  padding: 14px;
  border-color: #fceec1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.alert-message.block-message ul, .alert-message.block-message p {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
.alert-message.block-message ul {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.alert-message.block-message li {
  color: #404040;
}
.alert-message.block-message .alert-actions {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.alert-message.block-message.error, .alert-message.block-message.success, .alert-message.block-message.info {
  color: #404040;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.alert-message.block-message.error {
  background-color: #fddfde;
  border-color: #fbc7c6;
}
.alert-message.block-message.success {
  background-color: #d1eed1;
  border-color: #bfe7bf;
}
.alert-message.block-message.info {
  background-color: #ddf4fb;
  border-color: #c6edf9;
}
.alert-message.block-message.danger p a,
.alert-message.block-message.error p a,
.alert-message.block-message.success p a,
.alert-message.block-message.info p a {
  color: #404040;
}
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/G7kRH/
Updated Preview With Alert Message: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/G7kRH/2/

Comment: To expand this comment, how would I display the modal like you've shown and then if the message was sent successfully or something like that it would close the modal window and then display an alert at the top of the screen?

Comment: Sure, I updated my answer to add an alert when the user closes the modal.

Answer (score 2):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form

If you're using jQuery, it's not a far leap to include and utilize jQuery UI. Take a look over this demo and see if it helps out.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [jQuery BlockUI Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/). The first demo, the Login Form, on the [Demos tab](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#demos) does something like what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's modal dialog http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-message.

Which is easy to use and supports theme and lots of customization.